# make node server wait for client input before continuing

Tags: node.js, server, client, client-server

I have a nodejs app that has a finite specific sequence of actions.
One of the actions is getting an array of images, sending it to a client, and displaying it for a manual human filtering.
After filtering was done, (say a button was pressed), I need the nodejs app to keep executing the sequence until it's done.

I've been wondering over and over how to perform such a thing (and if possible, without the use of sockets.)

I tried creating a boolean representing if filtering was done, and using 
`while (!boolean)`, but server seems to be busy running it so it can't event handle the response which should update that same boolean.

Is there a better way?